# how to host C# console app on cloud

Tags: c#, console-application, paas

I was reading an article [How to create your own auto direct message Twitter bot for free](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-create-your-own-auto-direct-message-twitter-bot-for-free-e851265ce730). It uses Twitter's streaming API and NodeJS to send the auto DM. It uses Heroku to host the NodeJS app.

I was wondering that I can create same application in C# as a console app, but how can I host it on cloud or PaaS provider? If I have AWS EC2/Azure Windows VM then I can run the app forever on it and it will send auto DM but is there any PaaS provider which allows me to host continuously running C# console app?

PS : I am not talking about .NET Core. This is normal .NET based C# Windows console app. If there is solutions in .NET Core I would be happy to know.

Comment: I am not sure what's so special about the application being "continuously running". It's just a normal app, run it in your favorite PaaS provider

Comment: Heroku doesn't support c# which are other PaaS providers.

Comment: Heroku is just a tool for deployment. You don't need it at all.

Comment: You can build docker image from your .net core app and host it on heroku

Comment: Docker image and .NET core could be a solution but I am looking for solution similar to NodeJS deployment on Heroku? Is it possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can host it as an Azure WebJob, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-create-web-jobs, or Azure Function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference.

Answer (score 0):

If docker is an option for you: You could put your application into an Mono-Docker Container and deploy it on a docker host.
As a simple example:
https://thenewstack.io/getting-started-with-mono-on-docker/

Comment: If I don't want to go docker way then is there any other option, similar to NodeJS deployment on Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

"Azure Function" is the most effective solution to run this program as PaaS on Azure. Since it is a console app and background process. We can get below benefits by doing this on Azure Function,
 01. Less cost - we can configure "consumption" hosting plan.
 02. We don't need to worry much about hosting. We can directly do the codes on online editor. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-azure-function